# Immutability and collections

Tags: c#, collections, immutability

Hello I've got a questation, is this bad approach to immutability? And if it is, why? I mean for me if you adding or removing items to or from collection, you are not changing the state of the object, it still has one and the same collection. It doesn't really matter how many and if collection has items when you itterating it. When you ask for it, you will get allways different reference which you can not modify. If this is bad practice where are pros in using immutable collections?

Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    private readonly List<object> items;

    public object[] Items { get { return this.items.ToArray(); } }

    public Test(params object[] items)
    {
        this.items = new List<object>();
        this.items.AddRange(items);
    }

    public void AddItem(object item)
    {
        this.items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are adding/removing items from a list, it isn't an immutable list by definition.

Comment: Yeah usually if you want a readonly list you don't also want to be changing it when ever you want. You might be more interested in encapsulation?

Comment: I... I don't even know what to say to this one.

Comment: @maccettura Apparently you figured *something* out.

Comment: @Servy Technically correct -- the best kind of correct

Comment: I mean you are not changing the state of "Test"...

Comment: @moozy.wu Well, it's changing something. And what it changes is relevant to whether `Test` is considered immutable or not. This should suggest to you that your understanding of immutability is wrong. It should certainly not suggest to you that *everybody but you* has completely misunderstood a concept that you only just heard about for the first time. Would a linked list be "immutable" if you only add items in the middle? Of course not.

Comment: @moozy.wu immutability and readonly are not the same thing.  Besides this code not making a whole lot of sense, its certainly not immutable.  The fact that you can _add_ to your list should immediately tell you that.  If you had a public property that took a `List<object>` and it _replaces_ your private field `items` then that would be immutable.  You could not _change_ items, only make it an entirely new thing.  Look at System.String for an example of this.  You never modify a string, you only ever create a new string

Comment: There are built-in immutable collections. Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable(v=vs.111).aspx and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time/

Comment: @EdPlunkett By that definition of immutability, none of the types in `System.Collections.Immutable` are actually immutable.

Answer (score 1):

> is this bad approach to immutability?

It is.

If something is immutable, its state cannot change after its constructor returns.

Look at what your `AddItem` method is doing:

```
public void AddItem(object item)
{
    this.items.Add(item);
}
```

`items` is one of the class' fields and you are adding stuff to it. This is an example of "changing the state after construction".

"Wait a minute, the outside code can only access `items` by accessing the property `Items`, which will create a new reference every time that the client code cannot mutate!" you might say.

You are saying that on the assumption that the client code will only ever pass around `Test.Items`, which indeed, when mutated doesn't affect the `Test` object's state. However, what if someone wrote something like this:

```
public static void Foo(Test test) {
    test.AddItem(new object());
}
```

This method is clearly mutating the parameter passed in, isn't it? You might do something like this:

```
Test t = new Test("Hello");
var itemsBefore = t.Items;
Foo(t);
var itemsAfter = t.Items;
```

If `Test` were immutable, `itemsBefore` and `itemsAfter` should have the same items. Yet in reality, they are not the same. This means that `Test` is mutable.

If you want to make it immutable, you should make `AddItem` return a new `Test` object with the new item added in.

Comment: Yeyeye I understand this part. I think i might be looking the wrong way at collections not immutability itself, thank you :)

Comment: @moozy.wu If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!